# Stream from a mongodb cursor to Express response in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am toying around with all the fancy node.js/mongodb/express platforms, and stumbled across a problem:

```
app.get('/tag/:tag', function(req, res){
  var tag=req.params.tag;
  console.log('got tag ' + tag + '.');
  catalog.byTag(tag,function(err,cursor) {
     if(err) {
       console.dir(err);
       res.end(err);
     } else {
       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

       //this crashes
       cursor.stream().pipe(res);

     }
  });
});
```

As you probably guessed, `catalog.byTag(tag, callback)` does a `find()` query to Mongodb and returns the cursor

This leads to an error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
```

According to [mongodb driver doc](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursorstream.html), 
I tried to pass this converter to `stream()`:

```
function(obj) {return JSON.stringify(obj);}
```

but that does not help.

Can anybody tell me how to correctly stream something to a response?

Or is the only solution a boilerplate to manually pump the data using the 'data' and 'end' events?

Comment: does it work if you replace catalog.byTag with the direct call to MongoDB native driver?

Comment: No, same error.
Also, I can call `toArray()` and send that via `res.json()`, which works, but I would prefer streaming instead of buffering on the server and sending it out afterwards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A working combination of other answers here

```
app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
  Comment.find()
    .cursor()
    .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
    .pipe(res.type('json'))
})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor

- `cursor()` returns a Node streams3 compatible stream and is preferred over the deprecated `query.stream()` interface.
- Piping to `JSONStream.stringify()` to combine documents into an array instead of single objects
- Piping to `res.type('json')` which sets the HTTP `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and returns itself (the response stream) again.

Comment: This doesn't produce valid JSON, though, it just concatenates the stringified objects together instead of wrapping it properly in an array.

Comment: @robertklep you are right! I did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: since we are dealing with express, it seems some error handling is required here. I would like to see some recommended pattern.

Comment: @robertklep  what's the alternative, for a valid JSON output?

Comment: @Tiago the current answer will work (my comment referred to a previous version of the answer that has since been editted and fixed).

Comment: this would be great! if only [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) weren't deprecated... what to use instead for `JSONStream.stringify()`? I tried to write my own but failed miserably...

Comment: This works fine but how to handle error thrown by pipeline like wrong operator ?

Comment: @Shubham: I'm not sure. Maybe you can try `cursor().on('error', handler).pipe()...`?

Comment: @Shubham: actually, it seems you should check the query for errors first. `query.error()` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-error

Answer (score 22):

Use the cursor stream in combination with [`JSONStream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) to pipe it to your response object.

```
cursor.stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

Comment: (And make sure you `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');` before, as your response will otherwise be interpreted as text.)

Answer (score 9):

Simple. `.stream({transform: JSON.stringify});`

Answer (score 3):

Your mongo stream is dumping objects into the res stream which can only handle strings or buffers (hence the error).

Luckily, streams are easy to pipe together so its not too hard to make a transform stream to stringify your data.

in node v0.10.21:

```
var util = require('util')
var stream = require('stream')
var Transform = stream.Transform

util.inherits(Stringer, Transform)

function Stringer() {
  Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true } )
  // 'object mode allows us to consume one object at a time

}

Stringer.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  var pretty = JSON.stringify(chunk, null, 2) 
  this.push(pretty) // 'push' method sends data down the pike.
  cb() // callback tells the incoming stream we're done processing 
}

var ss = new Stringer()

db.createObjectStreamSomehow()
  .pipe(ss)
  .pipe(res)
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Using mongoose and express:

```
function(req, res){
    var stream = database.tracks.find({}).stream();
    stream.on('data', function (doc) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and recent solution for this problem:

```
const { JsonStreamStringify } = require("json-stream-stringify");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const cursor = db.collection("hello").find({}).limit(10).stream();
  x = new JsonStreamStringify(cursor).pipe(res);
  x.on("data", (doc) => {
    res.write(doc);
  });
});
```

The above solution is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream-stringify package.