# JSON string directly from node mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been doing a series of load tests on a simple server to try and determine what is negatively impacting the load on my much more complicated node/express/mongodb app. One of the things that consistently comes up is string manipulation require for converting an in-memory object to JSON in the express response.

The amount of data that I'm pulling from mongodb via node and sending over the wire is ~200/300 KB uncompressed. (Gzip will turn this into 28k which is much better.)

Is there a way to have the native nodejs mongodb driver stringify the results for me? Right now for each request with the standard .toArray() we're doing the following:

1. Query the database, finding the results and transferring them to the node native driver
2. Native driver then turns them into an in-memory javascript object
3. My code then passes that in-memory object to express
4. Express then converts it to a string for node's http response.send using JSON.stringify() (I read the source Luke.)

I'm looking to get the stringify work done at a c++/native layer so that it doesn't add processing time to my event loop. Any suggestions?

Edit 1:

It *IS* a proven bottleneck.

There may easily be other things that can be optimized, but here's what the load tests are showing.

We're hitting the same web sever with 500 requests over a few seconds. With this code:

```
app.get("/api/blocks", function(req, res, next){
    db.collection('items').find().limit(20).toArray(function(err, items){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.send(200, items);
    });
});
```

overall mean: 323ms, 820ms for 95th%

If instead I swap out the json data:

```
var cached = "[{... "; //giant json blob that is a copy+paste of the response in above code.
app.get("/api/blocks", function(req, res, next){
    db.collection('items').find().limit(20).toArray(function(err, items){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.send(200, cached);
    });
});
```

mean is 164 ms, 580 for 95th%

Now you might say, "Gosh Will a mean of 323ms is great, what's your problem?" My problem is that this is an example in which stringify is causes a doubling of the response time.

From my testing I can also tell you these useful things:

- Gzip was a 2x or better gain on response time. The above is with gzip
- Express adds a nearly imperceptible amount over overhead compared to generic nodejs
- Batching the data by doing cursor.each and then sending each individual item to the response is way worse

Update 2:

Using a profiling tool: https://github.com/baryshev/look
This is while hitting my *production* code on the same database intensive process over and over. The request includes a mongodb aggregate and sends back ~380KB data (uncompressed).

[image: premature optimization my foot!]

That function is very small and includes the `var body = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces);` line.

Comment: Do you have evidence that `JSON.stringify()` is taking significant time?  Besides, the implementation of `JSON.stringify` within node.js's V8 engine is likely in C++ anyway.

Comment: I agree with JohnnyHK. This looks like a case of premature optimization and should be fixed only after you've proven it is a bottleneck in your particular application. There are probably many more examples of perf issues which are going to get you more bang for you buck to solve.

Comment: Sounds like a quintessential use case for Streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should just stream directly from Mongo to Express.

Per [this question that asks exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20058614/1339987):

```
cursor.stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

Comment: In my test harness, this is nearly a 50% reduction in response time. Woo!