# Stream objects from MongoDB cursor into nodejs HTTP response

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, httpresponse

NOTE: I don't believe this question [is a duplicate of this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js) because it is more specific.

I'm attempting to retrieve multiple objects from Mongo with the nodejs-mongodb-driver and write the objects to an HTTP response as JSON. The objects should be in the form of an array, but i don't want to call `toArray()` on the cursor because of the memory overhead and I try to avoid large `JSON.stringify` calls whenever possible.

```
var response = ... // an http response
collection.find().stream(JSON.stringify).pipe(response); // causes a malformed JSON string
```

The object in the browser appears as follow.

```
{"obj", "obj"}{"obj", "obj"} // clearly malformed
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I will explain the code you wrote so that you understand why it returns malformed JSON and why you probably need `toArray()` or the JSONStream libary from the answer you posted.

First `collection.find()` returns a `Cursor` object. At that point no data was read. Then, the `.stream(JSON.stringify)` call returns a readable `Stream` with the transformation function `JSON.stringify`. Still no data read.

The `.pipe(response)` call then reads the entire `Stream` to the end and for every object it calls the `JSON.stringify` function. Note that it does really call it for every single `object` seperately and therefore does not create an `array`. Instead you get your *malformed* JSON, `object` after `object`.

Now the answer in the question you posted as possible duplicate ([Stream from a mongodb cursor to Express response in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js)) would work for you, but it requires an additional libary with a `JSONStream`. The JSONStream properly handles the `CursorStream` for `JSON` output. I don't know if that really reduces the overhead though, but you could try that.

Without an addition libary you will have to use `toArray()`.

Comment: I know why its malformed. I'm asking for an efficient way to do this. If there's an additional library why don't you suggest one.

Comment: you already posted that answer in your first line of the question. and i still think toArray is efficient. have you done tests? The library is in the answer of the question that you thought was not a duplicate.