# Handle mongodb error when streaming directly to express response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, stream

I just begin using the [mongodb stream functionality](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/) to stream data directly to the [express response](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res).

For that, I use the piece of code that is found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20891215/291541):

```
cursor.stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

I want to mark response with a 500 status when the cursor returns MongoError. Unfortunately, with this code, the error is returned in JSON with a 200 status.

How can I handle that using simple solutions? Do I have to handle that in the error event of the cursor? If so, how can I tell not to stream directly to express response if an error occurred?

**EDIT**

I've tried a solution with handling the error event on the stream like this:

```
var stream = cursor.stream();
stream.on('error', function(err){
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});
stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

Unfortunately, when an error occurred, I've got an `Error: write after end`
from express because I've already sent the response in the error event.

How can I flag response with an error status when the cursor-stream failed AFTER I have piped it to response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WriteStream is ended when ReadStream ends or has an error.

So you need to somehow prevent this default behaviour when errors happen during pipe. You can do that by passing `{end: false}` as pipe option.

This option alters default behavior so that even if the error occurs, your write stream is still open and you can keep sending more data down (e.g. error status).

```
var stream = cursor.stream();

stream.on('error', function () {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});

stream.on('end', function(){
  //Pipe does not end the stream automatically for you now
  //You have to end it manually
  res.end(); 
});

stream.pipe(res, {end:false}); //Prevent default behaviour
```

More information can be found on:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

Comment: Hmm.. The linked documentation says: "One important caveat is that if the Readable stream emits an error during processing, the Writable destination is not closed automatically. If an error occurs, it will be necessary to manually close each stream in order to prevent memory leaks.". So it seems that write stream is not ended on read stream error.