# Speed up data retrieval in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written one get API which fetches all data from mongodb collection converts it to array and returns it. But as the data is huge it takes some time to fetch data and send. How can I speed up the operation?
Please find below code,

```
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("unable to fetch data from collection",err);
            res.status(201).json({error : 'Unable to fetch data'});
        }
        else{
            console.log("data send");
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    })
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js

Comment: You should paginate using skip and limit. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find

Comment: It's kind of broad to ask a question without specifically stating what your intent is for the cursor results. If it *"takes a long time because data is huge"(sic)* then you probably don't want an array and you more likely want to do "something" else with the data. What that "something" is, we don't know unless you say. So just pointing you at the various cursor iteration and stream piping methods.