# Express.js: stream result from Mongo and serialize non-blockingly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, generator

What I'm trying to do, is update [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124486/214446) to not depend on the [JSONStream library](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream), which isn't maintained anymore. There we have:

```js
Comment.find()
  .cursor()
  .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
  .pipe(res.type('json'))
```

It's using the Mongoose `.cursor()`, which returns a [Node.js-compatible readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), but I'm open to using the native mongo driver.

Now, my first question: is anybody still using Node.js streams or are you nowadays supposed to use JavaScript Iterators and Generators?

If so, I think I'll be able to [convert the cursor to an iterator](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_streams_compatibility_with_async_generators_and_async_iterators) and convert each chunk to JSON separately. (Although library recommendations that do error-handling etc. are welcome, even if off-topic here and not the core of this question).

But how do I make the iterator stream into the express.js result?

I couldn't find any documentation on that (although couldn't find documentation on `res` being a writable stream either, although it works.) Am I even on the right track with my thinking here?

**Edit:**

Meanwhile, I've done some more research and found the following libs:

- [pull-stream](http://pull-stream.github.io) – with no TypeScript typings but with the creator of JSONStream as a contributor
- [ts-stream](https://github.com/poelstra/ts-stream/) – with [no built-in node stream conversion](https://github.com/poelstra/ts-stream/issues/17)
- [scramjet](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet) – looks intriguing... maybe a bit overkill, but at least comes with implementations of `map` and `filter` etc. for their streams..?

Comment: Scramjet won't have JSONStream's functionality until we manage to write the new version.

I'll take a look at JSONStream and try to get in touch with them - maybe we'd take it over to support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Added a custom stringifying step.

The `res` object in ExpressJS is a Writable subclassed from [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), and can be piped data.

I tend to hook up this data flow using NodeJS' built-in support for converting an iterator to a readable, and using `stream.pipeline` for exception handling.

> Note that it's no longer necessary to convert the cursor to a readable in NodeJS v13+, as stream.pipeline now accepts async iterators in place of a stream.

> Note that it is redundant to use `stringify()` if it is possible to use Mongoose's [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) directly. Lean will emit JSON data.

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

function handler(req, res, next){
  try {
    // init the cursor
    const cursor = Comment.find().lean(); // "lean" will emit json data
    const readable = stream.Readable.from( cursor );
    // promisifying the pipeline will make it throw on errors
    await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)( readable, res.type('json') );
    next();
  }
  catch( error ){
    next( error );
  }
}
```

With custom stringifying in NodeJS v13+:

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

function handler(req, res, next){
  try {
    // init the cursor
    const cursor = Comment.find().lean(); // "lean" will emit json data
    const readable = stream.Readable.from( cursor );
    // promisifying the pipeline will make it throw on errors
    await util.promisify(stream.pipeline)( 
      readable,
      // Custom "stringifying" using an async iterator
      async function*( source ){
        // Add some output before the result from mongodb. Typically, this could be information about 
        // the number of results in a REST API.
        yield "Appended"

        for await (const comment of source ){
          // Emit a "projection" of the data retrieved from MongoDB 
          yield {
            text: comment.text,
            // Add a new property:
            newProperty: true
          }
        }
        // Add some final data to the response. In a REST API, this might be the closing bracket of an array "]".
        yield "Prended"
      },
      // the stringified data is then piped to express' res object
      res.type('json') 
    );
    next();
  }
  catch( error ){
    next( error );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, good to hear an up-to-date voice on this! so, in practice we slightly modify the objects in js, so we cannot use the `.lean()` call and also need a `stringify` function, do you know of one? Also, we quickly checked the mongo native driver and it seemed much more performant than mongoose?! but need more benchmarking... (I also put in an edit in the question)

Comment: Personally, I tend to use mongoose for lightweight APIs like querying and inserts. However, for heavy duty fetching (10GB+) the native lib's cursors appear to use less memory. We use mongodb for both active querying and as a data lake simultaneously.