# Mongoose stream an aggregation query using async iterators

Tags: json, express, mongoose, async-await, aggregation-framework

I want to stream the results of an aggregation query using Mongoose so as to allow the client to handle a huge JSON response (eventually piping into a CSV transformer).

So far my code:

```
const pipeline = [
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$samples',
        // The name of a new field to hold the array index of the element.
        includeArrayIndex: 'num_sample',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
   {
       $limit: 10000,
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        t: '$samples.t',
        station: '$station.name',
        loc: '$station.location',
        data: '$samples.data',
      },
    },
  ];
  // const samples = await fixed.aggregate([pipeline]);

  const cursor = fixed
    .aggregate(pipeline)
    .cursor({ batchSize: 1000 })
    .exec();
 res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });
 res.write('[');
 await cursor.eachAsync(async (doc, i) => {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));
    res.write(',');
  });
  res.write('{}]');
  res.end();
```

But how to pipe the response to a CSV transformer as `json2csv`?
The code above is functionally correct?
I had to write additional chars to the response stream to have a JSON correctly formatted but the solution found (with a final {}) introduces an empty record in the final JSON (I have not found a way to write "," after each document returned from mongoose cursor except for the last one, for this reason, I had to introduce an empty record).

Answer (score 0):

Its a stream which means you have to `pipe` that stream to `res`, something like this:

```
cursor.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with the following code.

Any suggestion to improve the provided solution is welcome.

```
exports.get_FIXED_Samples_CSV = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // retrieve start and end dates
  // if start is not provided then set it to current date - 30 days
  const startDate =
    moment(req.query.start).isValid() && req.query.start
      ? moment(new Date(req.query.start))
      : moment(new Date()).subtract(30, 'd');

  // if end is not provided or invalid set it to current date
  const endDate =
    moment(req.query.end).isValid() && req.query.end
      ? moment(new Date(req.query.end))
      : moment(new Date());

  // retrieve station name and check if valid,if not returns null
  const station = [
    'AQ101',
    'AQ102',
    'AQ103',
    'AQ104',
    'AQ105',
    'AQ106',
    'AQ107',
  ].includes(req.query.station)
    ? req.query.station
    : null;

  // eslint-disable line no-unused-vars
  const pipeline = [
    // sort by date DESC adn station.name ASC
    {
      $sort: {
        'station.name': 1,
        date: -1,
      },
    },
    // unwind by samples array adding num_sample counting
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$samples',
        // The name of a new field to hold the array index of the element.
        includeArrayIndex: 'num_sample',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ set limit to returning docs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    {
      $limit: 216000,
    },
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // select fields to show
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        t: '$samples.t',
        station: '$station.name',
        loc: '$station.location',
        data: '$samples.data',
      },
    },
  ];

  // add as first stage to the pipeline a match aggregation
  if (station) {
    // if valid station  is provided
    pipeline.unshift({
      $match: {
        'station.name': station,
        date: {
          $gte: new Date(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
          $lte: new Date(endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
        },
      },
    });
  } else {
    // if station is INVALID OR NOT provided
    pipeline.unshift({
      $match: {
        date: {
          $gte: new Date(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
          $lte: new Date(endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
        },
      },
    });
  }

  // transform to apply to generate CSV
  const custTransf = (item, strFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss') => ({
    utc: item.t,
    t: moment(item.t).format(strFormat),
    station: item.station,
    ...item.data,
  });
  // Unwind Samples properties and flatten arrays
  const transforms = [
    // flatten({ objects: false, arrays: true }),
    custTransf,
  ];
  // const fields = ['t', 'station', 'data'];
  const opts = { transforms };
  const transformOpts = { highWaterMark: 8192 };
  const pipeTransf = new Transform(opts, transformOpts);
  // remove data prefix from fields
  const regex = /(data.)/gi;
  const filename = 'FixedStations';
  const strAtt = `attachment;filename=${filename}-${startDate.format(
    'YYYY-MMM-DD'
  )}-${endDate.format('YYYY-MMM-DD')}.csv`;
  res.header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Disposition',
    strAtt
    // 'attachment;filename=download.csv'
  );
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');

  const cursor = fixed
    .aggregate(pipeline)
    .allowDiskUse(true)
    .cursor({ transfor: JSON.stringify, batchSize: 1000 })
    .exec()
    .pipe(JSONStream.stringify())
    .pipe(pipeTransf)
    .pipe(replace(regex, ''))
    .pipe(res);
});
```