# Monitor progress of .find with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, progress-bar

I am running a full stack application with express.js in the backend. I have added some code below for a simple SELECT * function. The reviews database has around 32000, entries so it takes a little while to load. Is there any way for one to monitor the progress of the find query so I can create something like a progress bar for the user?

```
  module.exports.getReviews = async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  console.log('before func')

  const stream = Review.find({}).stream();

  stream.on('error', function () {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});

  stream.on('end', function(){
    //Pipe does not end the stream automatically for you now
    //You have to end it manually
    res.end(); 
  });

  stream.pipe(res, {end:false}); //Prevent default behaviour
  res.status(200).send(stream);

}
```

Comment: You can try the NodeSJ Driver's [Command Monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/monitoring/command-monitoring/) - it _may be possible_ to use this feature for your requirement. That said, Mongoose may have similar feature.

Comment: If instead I try to stream it like this: ```   const cursor = Review.find({}).cursor();

  for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {
    console.log(doc); // Prints documents one at a time
    res.status(200).json(doc);
  } ``` would i be able to send multiple responses back, per 1 request

Comment: But 32000 responses is not what you may be interested in. You may want to look at the `cursor#stream` method which returns a `Readable` stream  Readable streams are particularly useful to load data in manageable chunks and efficiently. The _events_ from the stream will point of the start, end of the stream and loading of data. _Another option is, to use _pagination_.

Comment: It says that the stream() function is depricated

Comment: As of MongoDB NodeJS Driver v4.2 API - it is valid.

Comment: I have updated my code... can you please help me understand this circular dependency. I think it has to do with sending the data back. The error is ```     : JSON.stringify(value);
           ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the c ```

Comment: ` res.status(200).send(stream);` - you need to use the NodeJS stream APIs to send data. See this SO post: [Stream from a mongodb cursor to Express response in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js), Also, you can also search for similar answers using the search string _"mongodb stream data node js"_.