# MongoDB Error: Cannot run getMore on cursor without an lsid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been searching for an answer online for the past day, to no avail.

My collection has over 1m documents.  My collection schema looks like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("61c26416e3c899307cf0507b")"id" : 6,
  "name" : "Pumped Up Kicks",
  "slogan" : "Faster than a just about anything",
  "description" : "The Pumped Up serves up crisp court style with a modern look. These shoes show off tennis-whites shades and are constructed with a supple leather upper and a classic rubber cupsole.",
  "category" : "Kicks",
  "default_price" : 89
}
```

The query I am trying:

```
products
    .find()
    .forEach(doc => console.log(doc))
```

Just a simple query to start out, trying to familiarize myself with how MongoDB handles querying large amounts of data.  I *am* trying to return all documents so that I may perform an action on them afterward.  As of now, I am unable to proceed beyond this point.  I am receiving this error as soon as I execute the code:

```
MongoServerError: Cannot run getMore on cursor 2168550933558261062, which was created in session 2197b8e7-1fec-4c0a-84ea-121a380ae69f - 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=, without an lsid
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/Users/joshfuqua/HackReactor/SDC/product-overview/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:462:30)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at processIncomingData (/Users/joshfuqua/HackReactor/SDC/product-overview/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/Users/joshfuqua/HackReactor/SDC/product-overview/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 50737,
  codeName: 'Location50737'
}
```

Also, limiting the query results to a few thousand yields the same result.  It appears to only allow me to query less than 100 at a time.

I have checked in multiple forums, the [MongoDB Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/), the [MongoDB API Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/index.html), and have yet to find anything.  The only thing I've been able to find related to this "lsid" error are forum answers to similar questions referencing timeout issues.  As I said, this error is instantaneous.

I would greatly appreciate any help.  I will also gladly provide any other necessary info to help troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Are you able to query and print a few documents to start with - using `find().limit(10)`, for example.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes.  I can do up to about 500 before I start receiving that error.

Comment: Have you tried native NodeJS driver API function on the cursor, `cursor#stream()` - this returns a `Readable` stream. Streams allow efficient reading of data in chunks.

Comment: See this post: [Stream from a mongodb cursor to Express response in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058614/stream-from-a-mongodb-cursor-to-express-response-in-node-js)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been working.  
I am not familiar with the native NodeJS driver API function.  Would this do anything to help my MongoDB query run without error?

Comment: Where are you running your query from? Is it from a NodeJS program or from `mongo` shell or some other?

Comment: I've been attempting to run from NodeJS.
Just to update you, I've gotten through my initial problem, but I'm still trying to understand why I'm facing this issue.  I've read plenty about instances of people querying a MongoDB for hundreds of thousands of docs at a time, so I don't understand why I'm having a problem.

Comment: The `find` function returns a cursor. You have work with various functions on the cursor object to read the documents into to your program (from the database server). Lookup the _cursor functions_ and see how they work for different situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run getMore on cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911342/cannot-run-getmore-on-cursor)