# Cannot run getMore on cursor

Tags: mongodb

I have a really simple MongoDB `find` query which filters a fairly large collection on one field.

```
let client = new MongoClient(`mongodb://${ip}:27019/test`, { w: 0 })
client.connect()
const db = client.db(dbName)
const messages = db.collection('messages')

;(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const cursor = messages.find({ deviceId: '786b06a838163326023e7726bd6f42481cc6b1ab' })
      const allValues = await cursor.toArray()

      console.log(allValues)
      cursor.close()
    }
})()
```

Running the query once works fine. But when i try to run it **multiple times in sequence**, it immediately returns this error without returning any other result.

```
MongoServerError: Cannot run getMore on cursor 2366016547291243997, which was not created in a session, in session 6c5c71bf-88b2-45d7-b234-bf7bb93554b8 - 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/tobias/Github/BachelorArbeit/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:462:30)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/tobias/Github/BachelorArbeit/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/tobias/Github/BachelorArbeit/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 50799,
  codeName: 'Location50799',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 2, high: 1643509041, unsigned: true },
    signature: {
      hash: Binary {
        sub_type: 0,
        buffer: Buffer(20) [Uint8Array] [
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ],
        position: 20
      },
      keyId: 0
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { low: 2, high: 1643509041, unsigned: true }
}
```

Strangely it works when i set a low `limit` like `100`.

Googling the problem and looking at the other StackOverflow posts with this error did not help. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying Write Concern as `0` is the problem (I don't know why though)

```
let client = new MongoClient(`mongodb://${ip}:27019/test`, { w: 1 })
```

Changing it to `1` or the default value fixed the problem.